# how to sort alphabetically with the same department

Tags: sql, oracle

Display all departments sorted by their location in descending order. When multiple departments are located at the same location ID, show their names in alphabetical order.

SELECT location_id, department_name
FROM Departments
ORDER BY location_id DESC;

I don't understand how to do the part - When multiple departments are located at the same location ID, show their names in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a second level to the `ORDER BY` clause to fall back to sorting on the department name in the event that two or more department have the same location:

```sql
SELECT location_id, department_name
FROM Departments
ORDER BY location_id DESC, department_name;
```